# JS switch statement works only sometimes

Tags: javascript, arrays, switch-statement

I'm writing a program that removes vowels from str parameter and I've decided to use a switch statement to achieve this goal.
I'm pretty bad at explaining stuff so I'll give you an example:

> No offense but,\nYour writing is among the worst I've ever read

Should become

> N ffns bt,\nYr wrtng s mng th wrst 'v vr rd

But my output looks like this:

> N ffns bt,\nY**u**r wrtng s mng th wrst 'v vr r**a**d

The program decided to leave "u" and "a" for some reason. After nearly 1,5h of looking for a cause, I give up because I have literally no clue what I did wrong.

```js
function disemvowel(str) {
  let arr = str.split(''); // str -> arr
  for (let x = 0; x <= arr.length; x++) { // remove vowels
    switch(arr[x]) {
      case "a":
      case "e":
      case "i":
      case "o":
      case "u":
      case "A":
      case "E":
      case "I":
      case "O":
      case "U":
        arr.splice(x, 1);
        break;  
    }
  }
  str = arr.join([separator = '']) // arr -> str
  return str;
}
```

Comment: Try running your loop backwards, this is a classic error when traversing a result that mutates.

Comment: As a side note, JavaScript doesn't have named arguments. `[separator = '']` will evaluate to `''` (due to the argument being converted to a string). Just use `arr.join('')` directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The array length is changing after every `splice`. You can define the `length` at first and decrement `x` every time you delete an item:

```js
function disemvowel(str) {
  let arr = str.split(''); // str -> arr
  const length = arr.length;
  for (let x = 0; x < length; x++) { // remove vowels
    switch(arr[x]) {
      case "a":
      case "e":
      case "i":
      case "o":
      case "u":
      case "A":
      case "E":
      case "I":
      case "O":
      case "U":
        arr.splice(x, 1);
        x--;
        break;  
    }
  }
  str = arr.join([separator = '']) // arr -> str
  return str;
}

console.log(
  disemvowel("No offense but,\nYour writing is among the worst I've ever read")
);
```